# SVNKIT verbose messages on checkout and update etc

Tags: java, svnkit

I am using SVNKIT version 1.8.11 and would like to output a more verbose message to the console showing what files are being checked out or updated.

If have this snippet:

```
    System.out.println("Updating... '" + workingCopyDirectory.toString()  + "'");
    final SvnOperationFactory svnOperationFactory = new SvnOperationFactory();
    svnOperationFactory.setAuthenticationManager(getAuthManager().getAuthenticationManager());
    try {
        final SvnUpdate svnUpdate = svnOperationFactory.createUpdate();
        svnUpdate.setSingleTarget(SvnTarget.fromFile(workingCopyDirectory.toFile()));
        svnUpdate.setAllowUnversionedObstructions(false);
        svnUpdate.setDepth(SVNDepth.INFINITY);
        svnUpdate.run();
        System.out.println("Update of local code base '" + workingCopyDirectory.toString() + "' completed.");
    } finally {
        svnOperationFactory.dispose();
    }
```

Is there a way I can configure SVNKIT to tell me what file it is currently updating/checking out?